# When using Google's Cloud Speech and sending Speech Contexts the returned transcriptions are not returning expected results

Tags: google-cloud-speech

Ref see: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/128352542

We are having an issue where certain words added in the user's speech context are not being returned or prioritized.

When using phrase hints, the API will generally correctly transcribe the phrases or words supplied when uttered, however some words will not be transcribed no matter how you add them in phrase hints.

Config sent inside StreamingRecognitionConfig:

```
{  
   "config":{  
      "encoding":"LINEAR16",
      "sampleRateHertz":8000,
      "languageCode":"en-US",
      "enableWordTimeOffsets":true,
      "enableAutomaticPunctuation":false,
      "model":"default",
      "useEnhanced":true,
      "speechContexts":[  
         {  
            "phrases":[  
               "Bill Uhma",
               "Uhma",
               "I got coffee with Bill Uhma"
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Result when trying to say "I got coffee with Bill Uhma":

```
{
   "results":{
      "alternatives":[
         {
            "confidence":0.8440007,
            "transcript":"I got coffee with Bill Uma",
            "words":[
               {
                  "confidence":0.847875,
                  "word":"I"
               },
               {
                  "confidence":0.9265712,
                  "word":"got"
               },
               {
                  "confidence":0.98762906,
                  "word":"coffee"
               },
               {
                  "confidence":0.98762906,
                  "word":"with"
               },
               {
                  "confidence":0.9239746,
                  "word":"Bill"
               },
               {
                  "confidence":0.23432566,
                  "word":"Uma"
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "confidence":0.94561315,
            "transcript":"I got coffee with Bill Luma"
         },
         {
            "confidence":0.911253,
            "transcript":"I got coffee with Bill Guma"
         },
         {
            "confidence":0.91219664,
            "transcript":"I got coffee with Bill Houma"
         },
         {
            "confidence":0.94028026,
            "transcript":"I got coffee with Bill looma"
         },
         {
            "confidence":0.9403957,
            "transcript":"I got coffee with Bill bouma"
         },
         {
            "confidence":0.9403957,
            "transcript":"I got coffee with Bill goomah"
         },
         {
            "confidence":0.9403957,
            "transcript":"I got coffee with Bill Wilma"
         },
         {
            "confidence":0.938467,
            "transcript":"I got coffee with Bill Boomer"
         },
         {
            "confidence":0.9403957,
            "transcript":"I got coffee with Bill buma"
         },
         {
            "confidence":0.9403957,
            "transcript":"I got coffee with Bill Ooma"
         },
         {
            "confidence":0.9403957,
            "transcript":"I got coffee with Bill Gooma"
         }
      ],
      "confidence":0.8440007,
      "is_final":true,
      "transcription":"I got coffee with Bill Uma"
   }
}
```

The **received** transcription is "I got coffee with Bill Uma".

The **expected** transcription is "I got coffee with Bill Uhma".

As seen in the result, the provided hints do not appear in any of the 12 alternatives received.

Separating the phrase hints and only sending one of them has no effect on the result.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually not a bug but should rather be considered as a feature request to force the recognizer to use the provided [phrases/hints](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/RecognitionConfig) specially if the word/s in the phrase does not exist in its vocabulary. If you would notice, the confidence level for the word "Uma" is very low which probably suggest that the recognizer does not understand it (not in its vocabulary).

[File feature request here](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests)

Comment: The word we are sending with our phrases/hints is actually "Uhma" (not "Uma") and is not returned in any of the transcription results. I don't know that there would be a way to force the phrase/hint Uhma to be used in this situation. I do agree that it is likely that the word is not recognized or is not in the dictionary